Oracle Autonomous Linux 8 on OCI VMs Freezing During Automated DNF or Ksplice Processes
I'm experiencing an issue with several VMs running Oracle Autonomous Linux 8 on OCI. Occasionally, these instances completely freeze, even when there’s minimal to no active resource usage at the time.
Upon reviewing the logs, I've noticed a pattern where the last entries before the freeze are related to either DNF makecache or Ksplice. It seems that the freeze often happens when these automated processes are running.
I’ve tried standard troubleshooting steps, including checking for any unusual load or resource bottlenecks, but none seem to be the direct cause of the issue. Here are additional details about my setup:
Environment: Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI)
OS: Oracle Autonomous Linux 8
Automated Processes: OCI manages both Ksplice updates and DNF routines.
Has anyone encountered similar freezing issues with Oracle Autonomous Linux on OCI or experienced problems specifically related to Ksplice or DNF causing instability?
Any insights or suggestions for debugging or mitigating this would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!
